# Laravel mix - Versioning does not work

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-mix

I'm working on a fresh project using `Laravel 5.6` using `laravel-mix@2.1.14`. When I compile my assets using `npm run production`, they are not suffixed like they [should](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)

#### Note

Even when removing the `if mix.inProduction()` the versioning does not work

#### Questions

Am I the only facing this issue ? What should I do ?

#### webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
 .copyDirectory('resources/assets/images', 'public/images');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version();
}
```

Comment: currently having same issue as well. (my laravel-mix is `2.1.14`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Laravel 5.6's mix works differently now**. Instead of suffixing your compiled files with hashes, it now uses a url query in trying to access your assets.

Try opening your browser dev tools and look at how your page includes your assets. It will append an `id` param in the URL.

e.g. `GET /js/app.js?id=<SOME_HASH_HERE>`

Comment: So you do confirm that cache busting is working right ?

Comment: Yes. To inspect it yourself, look at your browser's dev tools.

Comment: @LéoCoco NB: you must use `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>` instead of `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` now to get correct resource URL with id.